# Cordova 2.2.0 and ios generating ipa file from teminal error

Tags: ios, cordova, ipa

I am using cordova 2.2.0 library for creating ipa file from terminal.
When I am using below command:
**xcrun -sdk iphoneos6.0 PackageApplication -v /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app -o /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/out_ipa/hello_app_test.ipa --sign "iPhone Developer: AKIO ITO (N5YRDPREK9)" --embed /private/var/root/Downloads/Dev_Test.mobileprovision**

I am getting this error:

Packaging application: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app' Arguments: embed=/private/var/root/Downloads/Dev_Test.mobileprovision verbose=1 output=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/out_ipa/hello_app_test.ipa sign=iPhone Developer: AKIO ITO (N5YRDPREK9) Environment variables: HOME = /var/root SUDO_GID = 4294967294 VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no MAIL = /var/mail/root SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-UvWSWr/Listeners USER = root LOGNAME = root __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x0:0:0 USERNAME = root PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home:/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.8.4:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools SUDO_USER = nobody SHELL = /usr/bin/false TERM = unknown SUDO_COMMAND = /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos6.0 PackageApplication -v /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app -o /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/out_ipa/hello_app_test.ipa --sign iPhone Developer: AKIO ITO (N5YRDPREK9) --embed /private/var/root/Downloads/Dev_Test.mobileprovision SUDO_UID = 4294967294 VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.12 Output directory: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/out_ipa/hello_app_test.ipa' Temporary Directory: '/tmp/oERgpr0ih1' (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set) + /bin/cp -Rp /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app /tmp/oERgpr0ih1/Payload Program /bin/cp returned 0 : [] ### Checking original app + /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app: code object is not signed at all In architecture: i386 ] Codesign check fails : /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AppHome/app/webroot/files/apps/iphone/hello_app_test/build/hello_app_test.app: code object is not signed at all In architecture: i386 Done checking the original app ### Embedding '/private/var/root/Downloads/Dev_Test.mobileprovision' + /bin/rm -rf /tmp/oERgpr0ih1/Payload/hello_app_test.app/embedded.mobileprovision Program /bin/rm returned 0 : [] + /bin/cp -rp /private/var/root/Downloads/Dev_Test.mobileprovision /tmp/oERgpr0ih1/Payload/hello_app_test.app/embedded.mobileprovision Program /bin/cp returned 0 : [] ### Codesigning '/private/var/root/Downloads/Dev_Test.mobileprovision' with 'iPhone Developer: AKIO ITO (N5YRDPREK9)' + /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Developer: AKIO ITO (N5YRDPREK9) --resource-rules=/tmp/oERgpr0ih1/Payload/hello_app_test.app/ResourceRules.plist /tmp/oERgpr0ih1/Payload/hello_app_test.app Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/tmp/oERgpr0ih1/Payload/hello_app_test.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources ]

Please help some one to create ipa file from terminal(MAC).
Any help and suggestion will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I only notice these:

1- code object is not signed at all In architecture: i386

2- ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources

check if your plist is valid (maybe some extra or missing character)